# Push Notification iOS resetting

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios6.1

I want to reset the push notification setting for my app. I have read the apple documentation regarding resetting the settings (which didn't help) and some questions here as well (which didn't help either). So in the last I reset my iPhone by going to settings->General->Reset ->Erase All Content and Settings (That didn't worked as well.)

Any other solution?

BTW I am using iOS 6.1

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on 6.1 as well!

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.

You can also move your clock by a day after uninstalling the app and try.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but did you even read my question? I clearly mentioned that **"I have read the apple documentation regarding resetting the settings (which didn't help)"**