# How do I reset push notification permissions in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios-simulator

I'm developing push notifications for an iOS app.

How do I reset the push notification permissions on an iOS simulator?

I've read this question: [Push Notification iOS resetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887708/push-notification-ios-resetting)

As per the Q&A above, I'm aware that you can't reset them easily on a normal phone.  But obviously there must be a way to develop around this feature (I hope).  I'm using a simulator.  This is all just fluff text because the question is actually really simple but if you make a question too short, people think you haven't done your research.  There is a certain length at which a question appears legitimate, and I think I've finally reached it.  To reiterate:

How do I reset the push notification permissions on an iOS simulator?

The only way I've found so far is to select from the top menu `Hardware > Erase all content and settings...`, but this makes for a pretty slow dev cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's the easiest and fastest thing you could do to reset the asking of every permissions in your app in simulator. `Hardware > Erase all content and settings`.

But why? Why do you need to do that? The much faster way is to write a `Unit Test` to test your function in handling the time the user grants or declines the asking of permission of your app.

OR if you don't feel like writing tests, just put a mock variable or something that would mock the **Allow** and **Don't Allow** events.

Comment: My circumstance is that I'm trying to test that when a user taps a "Enable push notifications" button, the permission request appears (only once).  Also, I wish my employer believed in testing.

Comment: It is guaranteed that the permission request appears ONCE. :) But not sure though if you spam (tap multiple times, fast) your `Enalbe Push Notif` button, if that's the case and it happens, you could add a debounce to prevent spamming of taps in that button. And it's understood that some companies and teams don't like writing test and rely on a manual QA, since writing unit test code takes time too. But writing a mock code in your controller won't hurt.